# .NET Web Service that takes email id as input and searches the Active Directory?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, active-directory

How to write a .NET Web Service that takes email id as input and searches the Active Directory to see if that user exists and returns a flag. I have an userID and Password that is used to query AD. Please describe how to do this and what else do I need?

Comment: C#, VB.NET? In both cases there are copious amounts of sample code at the other end of a quick Googling. Do you have code in place already that just isn't working for some reason? If not, I suggest you start by looking up DirectoryServices.

Comment: For one thing, don't use "ASP.NET web services", which are a legacy technology. Use WCF for all new development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using WCF, you can achieve this fairly easily.

**Step 1 - define a service contract**

This defines your operations that you want, including the parameters they might need. Not knowing what exactly you might need, I just guessed and came up with something like this:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace SearchAD
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISearchADService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool EMailAddressExists(string emailAddress);
    }
}
```

**Step 2 - implement the service class**

This means adding the "meat" to the bone (the service contract) - this is where you actually do what you're trying to do:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace SearchAD
{
    public class SearchADService : ISearchADService
    {
        public bool EMailAddressExists(string emailAddress)
        {
            // establish the Active Directory domain context to search in
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN", userName, password);

            // define your "query-by-example" user to search for    
            UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
            qbeUser.EmailAddress = emailAddress;

            // instantiate the searcher to find that user    
            PrincipalSearcher findUserByMail = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

            // search for the user - did we find one?    
            UserPrincipal userByEmail = findUserByMail.FindOne() as UserPrincipal;

            return userByEmail != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, in this setup - you'll need to get your domain name, the user name and the password (for querying Active Directory) from somewhere - a config file, constants in your service class - whatever works for you!

With this, you basically have your WCF service that takes an e-mail address and searches Active Directory for a user account matching that e-mail address. If found, `true` is returned - `false` otherwise.

Now, with your WCF service, you now only need to know how to host it (in IIS or self-hosting), and how to create clients for it to use the service - but that's just very basic WCF know-how, you shouldn't have any trouble finding the necessary infomrmation and tutorials, if you don't have that know-how already !

The mechanism used to search Active Directory is the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace, which is part of .NET 3.5 and newer. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This works absolutely well. By the way can I was not able to test the web service using SOAP UI tool. Then I changed the default binding to basichttpbinding in the config file. SOAP UI tool then detected it and was a ble to test successfully. It was same situation with WebServiceStudio.